# Disable Windows 11 data collection across an entire tenant for O365 Enterprise?

Tags: windows-11, office365, group-policy, privacy

I'm at my wit's end with how much Windows 11 is sending back in terms of information used for "personalized ads". The security policy I need to adhere to is very IP protective and basically any information that is sent to 3rd parties is considered a risk. There should be a way for me to disable these settings across my tenants and disable copilot and other data collection sinkholes right? I have Enterprise E3 for reference so I should be able to push out these settings to configure Windows 11 and Edge browser to restrict or eliminate these 3rd party data collection vectors.

My boss is sick of this to the point he's about to have me migrate everything to self hosted stuff in the cloud. I REALLY want to avoid that because it'll be a compliance nightmare from a maintenance and logging/auditing perspective. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It is impossible to completely disable some of the metrics that Microsoft collects, the only way that would be possible, if the machines were connected to a network where those endpoints didn’t exist.

Comment: @Ramhound, I agree and have no problem with say UI/UX metrics to improve UI design or other stuff like that. It's more the personalized ad data collection that gets under my skin that should be off by default for business accounts.